# best practice of javascript class method definition to calc food price with toppings

Tags: javascript, class, oop, model

I have started a restaurant and created software the determine the price of all the items on the menu
I started by creating a class for each menu item so that the price can be calculated using an interface.

```
interface HasPrice {
    getPrice(): number;
}

class Ramen implements HasPrice {
    getPrice() {
        return 5;
    }
}
class Spaghetti implements HasPrice {
    getPrice() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

She then decided there should be topping so she used the decorator pattern.

```
class RamenWithPork extends Ramen {
    getPrice() {
         super.getPrice() + 3;
    }
}
```

This worked until I decided to expand the topping menu and it became too cumbersome to deal combinatorial amount of classes. How should I fix it?

Comment: You could use the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) which relies on composition over inheritance to add dynamic behavior

Comment: First of all [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Second, your code seems like it's straight up ready for a [decorator design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). You can even invert the relationship and implement the price calculation as a [visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) or [strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Decorator pattern

OK, so this is the job of the [decorator design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) - you can *wrap* your objects in another that decorates them with extra behaviour. This solves the problem of convoluted dependency hierarchies. You've already experienced it but just to illustrate it - let's say you have

```
class Rament {}
class RamenWithPork extends Ramen {}
class RamenWithChicken extends Ramen {}
class RamenWithMushrooms extends Ramen {}
```

What happens if you have `RamenWithChickenAndMushroom`? Do you extend `RamenWithChicken` or `RamenWithMushrooms` or just `Ramen`? What if you have `RamenWithPorkMushroomsAndChicken`? First of all, can you even remember the name of this class - if you sit down a day later, can you remember if it was pork, chicken and mushrooms or pork, mushrooms and chicken? Second how do you model that in the class hierarchy?

Here is where the decorator pattern comes in - you can create *decorators* like:

```
interface OrderAddition {}
class WithChicken implements OrderAddition {}
class WithMushrooms implements OrderAddition {}
class WithPork implements OrderAddition {}
```

Which can then be used with any food. The `interface Extras` is here for convenience. It helps keep the dependency hierarchy focused and more practical - `HasPrice` is a bit too vague - anything can have a price, but with `OrderAddition` we know exactly what kind this is. Another way to call it is `OrderDecorator` - it's a bit drier but it's more descriptive and immediately calls out the design pattern used.

### Using classes

So, here is what your code can look like with decorators:

```
interface MainDish { //renaming it to be more descriptive
    getPrice(): number;
}

class Ramen implements MainDish {
    getPrice() {
        return 5;
    }
}
class Spaghetti implements MainDish {
    getPrice() {
        return 10;
    }
}

//decorators would need to do the same as the object they decorate, 
//so the decorator implements the MainDish interface
interface OrderAddition extends MainDish {} 

abstract class AbstractOrderAddition implements OrderAddition {
  protected base: MainDish;

  constructor(base: MainDish) {
    this.base = base;
  }

  abstract getPrice(): number;
}

class WithChicken extends AbstractOrderAddition {
    getPrice() {
      return this.base.getPrice() + 5
    }
}

class WithMushrooms extends AbstractOrderAddition {
    getPrice() {
      return this.base.getPrice() + 1
    }
}

class WithPork extends AbstractOrderAddition {
    getPrice() {
      return this.base.getPrice() + 3
    }
}
```

Which then allows you to do the following:

```
let order: MainDish = new Ramen();
order = new WithPork(order);
order = new WithMushrooms(order);
```

[Check on the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=59&pc=52#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLJ1AEWAZwBbIDeyA9CVBCHALagDmywYyYA9sgEYrWsXIAmEHAijAADmGAA3CAChkC5HQhgACqKQAKAJQAuZCACu1LlADcsgL6zZCADZwcOZACUalRtTF2I1SmGd0LFwCQnlFZTUNCB0icMVFCjBDKBBkAFYLBOtre0dnAGUxODo8FUlPb19-QIwQbHw4hMj1YC1tJoTElRS0gEYABizFHJsyQQReODYoZwB3VkM7fgMICBW2AXYwMuQcd2RHFl3WDgArCARmHYgATwFLqcgAGmRZMhxt3Ymn3kqfPzgZw3NB1BoEUCQWCIOSQ6DwJDIADyUEEUAAgvx+ExgKw0hAAB6QED8WrBRqESxvWRwDg4MBQRDMPJOZDoukMpkotGY7GSPH-apA5Go6C8nECsIKMRQViQK7rTiOCD6IL1EIWcKTED0qCGK68TQcZWqsEhDpSxQ7XAAOmNOBQAF4lQ6zKQSABrNZiY4oXjAOigOB2N4KazhWm6plKFStdr6IwmaAWcMs5wAdSYeAAwng2l78UTKKS2RzGVduWKsRK0paFC1orE691kqljrb7RAbQ22jEOgBqDLxZCjWwOVmZnaoQz4WWsajOQnEkvsqMV0UY6v82vDnvtToJJK9ds4O3K7uxxsD5B9YejtPISd4VS8D3IJfF5yrznrnlb3E7s0l69k2w4KEebbWqenYXlEIHXgAzHeVg2D4zAwMAsxgJWUCmuSBDOiAEBzK47ggDoFgYVhOHIIRxGPlmL5QB6mhUfSOHaJRmHsRutGrCRT7TrOrDzjgrHcdhG6cTY2qfD4Np2KwdCaAARGxkloiprzqThsFxn20myGheyPCSOF4eqjR0SRRQlGUYCSBRsgOtq-A0dZDE7Lm+aUJoLl4m5UkWP5Zm8R5T5MSxIWBWi0nRe5-GeXgQl4HOC5+aZMXQIZsmsPJinKSp8UblpJmubpe4GWYQA)

### Using decorator functions

This, however, is highly formal usage of decorators. In JavaScript, you can short-circuit some of this and still maintain the same idea. Instead of having *classes* you can have your decorators as functions that modify the instance they are given:

```
interface OrderAdditionMaker{
  (additionalPrice: number) : AddToOrder
}

interface AddToOrder {
  (base: MainDish) : MainDish
}

const withChicken: AddToOrder = function withChicken(base: MainDish): MainDish {
  //take a reference of the original
  const originalGetPrice: MainDish["getPrice"] = base.getPrice.bind(base);

  //overwrite the `getPrice` method
  base.getPrice = function(): ReturnType<MainDish["getPrice"]> {
    return originalGetPrice() + 5;
  }

  return base;
}
```

This can be further generalised into a more functional route by using [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) so you can easily derive all the decorator functions:

```
//interface for making decorators
interface OrderAdditionMaker{
  (additionalPrice: number) : AddToOrder
}

//decorator function
interface AddToOrder {
  (base: MainDish) : MainDish
}

const withExtra: OrderAdditionMaker = function (additionalPrice: number) {
  return function (base: MainDish): MainDish {
    const originalGetPrice: MainDish["getPrice"] = base.getPrice.bind(base);
    base.getPrice = function (): ReturnType<MainDish["getPrice"]> {
      return originalGetPrice() + additionalPrice;
    }

    return base;
  }
}

const withChicken: AddToOrder = withExtra(5);
const withMushrooms: AddToOrder = withExtra(1);
const withPork: AddToOrder = withExtra(3);
```

[Check on the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=52&pc=52#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLJ1AEWAZwBbIDeyA9CVBCHALagDmywYyYA9sgEYrWsXIAmEHAijAADmGAA3CAChkC5HQhgACqKQAKAJQAuZCACu1LlADcsgL6zZCADZwcOZACUalRtTF2I1SmGd0LFwCQnlFZTUNCB0icMVFCjBDKBBkAFYLBOtre0dnAGUxODo8FUlPb19-QIwQbHw4hMj1YC1tJoTElRS0gEYABizFHJsyUEhYRBQYXmRqOABregEIBF44NigcWQnoeCRkAHkoQSgAQX5+JmBWEHRF6DCFTTgrm7u4O1akfSMTaAdfSXfgAFVYJzOVjGJEE6ygmzmMEMIAQkjuu3A+2myBB4Mh0E6mg4jgg+iC9RCQLQdQaeGhtjuOGYAHcmHgAKIADzACP0BIu73R9yWhIAvMhkajhchXkLblRvtE-sZTB1nsgkr1JSi0QrZSScGSacF8HoTZTGhqFOsQMzkLxgHRQF8AOIqH7Gil0gDaACIWtE-QBdZASw0QAB0gbaUY4oH4xNJ2mGCgj0Y90TDOul+p0+hcPVSoIAnmIIAAeb0hf0xpAhgB8nQSWtSDtEzsV7qisdiAGpkG9rsKvp7U8hrPFNUW0hHhqNGXbWeyAMJ4NqPEDAq7407i5BssCcnkIzTpFOL+2HvCoQz4KCsVjUHDbsEQvdQbPX7m8uCaPoXraV7sqovCLK+u5nF+7I-qeADMF6yD4zAwMA2xgAK5K0iE2YgBALKuO4IA6BYqHoQK0FHqBUCLJoZHMgKF70RhH6UTed54A+T44HRaEMR+iFAawPiRnYrB0JofrMQKfoADSSnxLFnBmPbtIhyHIEatr8JhFp0rh+HIEUJRlGAkgkbIWl3DprEStea4bpQmhWSANlnBeLlufu17UbRnmMRY-m2Qe7K3vej7Ps5azWQFNhCSJYkSX6QVnHJmnRa5AoqZ6OgpkAA)